# google bar chart color for negative values or values less than 0

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I am looking for an option to make the color of google bar chart as 'RED' when values are less than 0. For now I have tried many things. But none work.

I have also checked *colorFormater* and the function *colorNegative* but that works only with the Table and not with *coreChart*. Below is the code I am using. Please suggest.

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['', 'Cost'],
          ['A', 20],
          ['B', 30 ],
          ['C', 50 ],
          ['D', 60],
          ['E', 90 ],
          ['F', 24 ],
          ['G', 40 ],
          ['H', 0],
          ['I', 0],
          ['J', -30 ],
          ['K', -54 ],
          ['L', -60]
      ]);

      var options = {

              width: 419,

              colors: ['#bac405','#f95602'],
            bars: 'horizontal',
            legend:'bottom',

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('function'));

      chart.draw(data,options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer for my question. Just added view to the bars.

Thanks to this link - http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/QHJA6/

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['', 'Cost'],
          ['A', 20],
          ['B', 30 ],
          ['C', 50 ],
          ['D', 60],
          ['E', 90 ],
          ['F', 24 ],
          ['G', 40 ],
          ['H', 0],
          ['I', 0],
          ['J', -30 ],
          ['K', -54 ],
          ['L', -60]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Value',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) < 0) ? dt.getValue(row, 1) : null;
        }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Value',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) > 0) ? dt.getValue(row, 1) : null;
        }
    }]);

      var options = {

              width: 419,

            colors: ['red','#bac405'],
            bars: 'horizontal',
            legend:'none',
            isStacked: true

      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('function'));

      chart.draw(view,options);

    }
```